# Picture size 0x10 is invalid | video codec is not opened.What should be the reason?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rtmp, libavcodec, video-codecs

Right now am using `RTMPStreamPublisher` to publish the video at wowzaserver from iphone application. i have downloaded some demo code from this GitHub Project https://github.com/slavavdovichenko/MediaLibDemos/tree/master/RTMPStreamPublisher.

Now this sample is working great..but when i tried to create my own project with the same implementation then its giving me some error...am sure that there is not any kind of missing library or framework issue.. i had checked everything is same in my created project as per the demo they given..

but still don't know where am doing mistake... my error is as follows..

```
[NULL @ 0x181a0c00] [IMGUTILS @ 0x27d78630] Picture size 0x10 is invalid
[NULL @ 0x181a0c00] ignoring invalid width/height values
[flv @ 0x181a0c00] Specified pix_fmt is not supported
video codec is not opened
2013-11-28 12:39:27.064 LiveStreaming[268:60b] AudioCodec: codecID = 86050, codecType = 42, bitRate = 16000, _sampleBytes = 4
encoder supports the sample formats:
flt, 
audio codec best options: sample_rate = 44100
[nellymoser @ 0x18179a00] Specified sample_fmt is not supported.
audio codec is not opened
```

i really don't know what's the real problem...as there is just generalize error of `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`
any idea??that what should be wrong??

```
NOTE: I am using following Library
```

Just after creating the project i had added libraries and frameworks to it. Using the CommLibiOS and MediaLibiOS libraries requires to add the following frameworks: CFNetwork, AudioToolbox, AVFoundation, CoreFoundation, CoreMedia, CoreVideo, Security, and library libz.dylib.

Then added CommLibiOS and MediaLibiOS libraries to the project.

following is my .h file

```
//
//  ViewController.h
//  RTMPStreamPublisher
//
//  Created by Vyacheslav Vdovichenko on 7/10/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 The Midnight Coders, Inc. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MediaStreamPlayer.h"
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import <CoreMedia/CoreMedia.h>

@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UITextField    *hostTextField;
    IBOutlet UITextField    *streamTextField;
    IBOutlet UIView         *previewView;
    IBOutlet UIButton *btnConnect;
    IBOutlet UIButton *btnToggle;
    IBOutlet UIButton *btnPublish;
    IBOutlet UILabel        *memoryLabel;

}

-(IBAction)connectControl:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)publishControl:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)camerasToggle:(id)sender;

@end
```

following is my .m file

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  RTMPStreamPublisher
//
//  Created by Vyacheslav Vdovichenko on 7/10/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 The Midnight Coders, Inc. All rights reserved.
//

#import "HomeViewController.h"
#import "DEBUG.h"
#import "MemoryTicker.h"
#import "BroadcastStreamClient.h"
#import "MediaStreamPlayer.h"
#import "VideoPlayer.h"
#import "MPMediaEncoder.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreMedia/CoreMedia.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>
#import "PhoneStreaming.h"
@interface HomeViewController () <MPIMediaStreamEvent> {
    MemoryTicker            *memoryTicker;
    RTMPClient              *socket;
    BroadcastStreamClient   *upstream;
}

-(void)sizeMemory:(NSNumber *)memory;
-(void)setDisconnect;
@end


@implementation HomeViewController

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark  View lifecycle

-(void)viewDidLoad {

    //[DebLog setIsActive:YES];

    [super viewDidLoad];

    memoryTicker = [[MemoryTicker alloc] initWithResponder:self andMethod:@selector(sizeMemory:)];
    memoryTicker.asNumber = YES;

    socket = nil;
    upstream = nil;

    //echoCancellationOn;

    //hostTextField.text = @"rtmp://80.74.155.7/live";
    //hostTextField.text = @"rtmp://10.0.1.33:1935/live";
    //hostTextField.text = @"rtmp://10.0.1.33:1935/videorecording";
    //hostTextField.text = @"rtmp://192.168.2.63:1935/live";
    //hostTextField.text = @"rtmp://192.168.2.63:1935/videorecording";
    hostTextField.text = @"rtmp://192.168.3.187:1935/live";
    //hostTextField.text = @"rtmp://192.168.2.101:1935/live";
    hostTextField.delegate = self;

    streamTextField.text = @"slavav";
    //streamTextField.text = @"outgoingaudio_c109";
    //streamTextField.text = @"myStream";
    streamTextField.delegate = self;


}


-(void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Private Methods

// MEMORY

-(void)sizeMemory:(NSNumber *)memory {
    memoryLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [memory intValue]];
}

// ALERT

-(void)showAlert:(NSString *)message {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Receive" message:message delegate:self
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [av show];
    });
}

// ACTIONS

-(void)doConnect {

    upstream = [[BroadcastStreamClient alloc] init:hostTextField.text];
    upstream.delegate = self;

    [upstream setPreviewLayer:previewView];


    [upstream stream:streamTextField.text publishType:PUBLISH_LIVE];

    //btnConnect.title = @"Disconnect";}
}

-(void)doDisconnect {
    [upstream disconnect];
}

-(void)setDisconnect {

    [socket disconnect];
    socket = nil;

    [upstream teardownPreviewLayer];
    upstream = nil;

   // btnConnect.title = @"Connect";
    btnToggle.enabled = NO;
   // btnPublish.title = @"Start";
    btnPublish.enabled = NO;

    hostTextField.hidden = NO;
    streamTextField.hidden = NO;

    previewView.hidden = YES;

}

-(void)sendMetadata {

    NSString *camera = upstream.isUsingFrontFacingCamera ? @"FRONT" : @"BACK";
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSDictionary *meta = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:camera, @"camera", [date description], @"date", nil];
    [upstream sendMetadata:meta event:@"changedCamera:"];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Public Methods

// ACTIONS

-(IBAction)connectControl:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"connectControl: host = %@", hostTextField.text);

    (!upstream) ? [self doConnect] : [self doDisconnect];
  }

-(IBAction)publishControl:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"publishControl: stream = %@", streamTextField.text);
    PhoneStreaming *add = [[PhoneStreaming alloc]
                                  initWithNibName:@"PhoneStreaming" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:add animated:YES completion:nil];

   // (upstream.state != STREAM_PLAYING) ? [upstream start] : [upstream pause];
}

-(IBAction)camerasToggle:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"camerasToggle:");

    if (upstream.state != STREAM_PLAYING)
        return;

    [upstream setVideoOrientation:
     upstream.isUsingFrontFacingCamera ? AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight : AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft];

    [upstream switchCameras];

    [self sendMetadata];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UITextFieldDelegate Methods

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark MPIMediaStreamEvent Methods

-(void)stateChanged:(id)sender state:(MPMediaStreamState)state description:(NSString *)description {

    NSLog(@" $$$$$$ <MPIMediaStreamEvent> stateChangedEvent: %d = %@ [%@]", (int)state, description, [NSThread isMainThread]?@"M":@"T");

    NSLog(@"SOCKET %@",socket.description);

    switch (state) {

        case CONN_DISCONNECTED: {

            [self setDisconnect];

            break;
        }

        case CONN_CONNECTED: {

            if (![description isEqualToString:MP_RTMP_CLIENT_IS_CONNECTED])
                break;

#if 0  // use encoder -> MPMediaEncoder instance
            upstream.encoder = [MPMediaEncoder new];
#endif
            [upstream start];



            break;

        }

        case STREAM_CREATED: {
            break;
        }

        case STREAM_PAUSED: {

          //  btnPublish.title = @"Start";
            btnToggle.enabled = NO;

            break;
        }

        case STREAM_PLAYING: {

            [self sendMetadata];

            [upstream setPreviewLayer:previewView];





            hostTextField.hidden = YES;
            streamTextField.hidden = YES;
            previewView.hidden = NO;


           // btnPublish.title = @"Pause";
            btnPublish.enabled = YES;
            btnToggle.enabled = YES;

            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }
}

-(void)connectFailed:(id)sender code:(int)code description:(NSString *)description {

    NSLog(@" $$$$$$ <MPIMediaStreamEvent> connectFailedEvent: %d = %@, [%@]", code, description, [NSThread isMainThread]?@"M":@"T");

    if (!upstream)
        return;

    [self setDisconnect];

    [self showAlert:(code == -1) ?
     @"Unable to connect to the server. Make sure the hostname/IP address and port number are valid" :
     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"connectFailedEvent: %@", description]];
}

/*/// Send metadata for each video frame
 -(void)pixelBufferShouldBePublished:(CVPixelBufferRef)pixelBuffer timestamp:(int)timestamp {

 //[upstream sendMetadata:@{@"videoTimestamp":[NSNumber numberWithInt:timestamp]} event:@"videoFrameOptions:"];

 //
 CVPixelBufferRef frameBuffer = pixelBuffer;

 // Get the base address of the pixel buffer.
 uint8_t *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(frameBuffer);
 // Get the data size for contiguous planes of the pixel buffer.
 size_t bufferSize = CVPixelBufferGetDataSize(frameBuffer);
 // Get the pixel buffer width and height.
 size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(frameBuffer);
 size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(frameBuffer);

 [upstream sendMetadata:@{@"videoTimestamp":[NSNumber numberWithInt:timestamp], @"bufferSize":[NSNumber numberWithInt:bufferSize], @"width":[NSNumber numberWithInt:width], @"height":[NSNumber numberWithInt:height]} event:@"videoFrameOptions:"];
 //
 }
 /*/

@end
```

Comment: You need to post the code, You are only posting the result. I don't know what you did wrong if I don't know what you did. I do find it highly unlikely you are using the nellymoser codec.

Comment: @szatmary please see my updated code i just added snippet of my code.